# Docker doesn't save permanently files, which create my java app

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose

My java app (backend) create some files during work. And when i make rebuild after some changes, this file deletes and my app need to create it again. How to save this files permanently? I try to create volume but it doesn't work.

This is my docker-compose config:

```
version: '3'

services:
  examledb:
    container_name: examle-docker-db
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - examle-docker-db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5555:5432"
    expose:
      - "5555"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=examle
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    networks:
      - examle-docker-network
    restart: unless-stopped

  backend:
    container_name: examle-docker-backend
    build: ./backend
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/docker/volumes/example_prod_example-backend-volume/_data:/root/projects/example_PROD/backend
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "8888:8888"
    depends_on:
      - examledb
    networks:
      - examle-docker-network
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://examle-docker-db:5432/examle
    restart: unless-stopped

  frontend:
    container_name: examle-docker-frontend
    build: ./frontend
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: serve -s dist/vu4y-frontend -l 4200
    networks:
      - examle-docker-network

  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable
    container_name: examle-docker-nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./data/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    depends_on:
      - frontend
      - backend
    networks:
      - examle-docker-network
    command: "/bin/sh -c 'while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g \"daemon off;\"'"
  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    networks:
      - examle-docker-network
    entrypoint: "/bin/sh -c 'trap exit TERM; while :; do certbot renew; sleep 12h & wait $${!}; done;'"

volumes:
  examle-docker-db: { }

networks:
  examle-docker-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Also I try to create volume like this:

```
volumes:
  - example-backend-volume:/root/projects/example_PROD/backend
```

It also doesn't work.

My docker-compose.yml layout in /root/projects/Example

Any advice will be very helpful. All files creates inside backend folder in the same category with src and pom.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. My problem was that I don't understand how docker's volume works. I thought that need to write root where my docker app is run, but need to write any path in right path (in my case `/root/projects/example_PROD/backend`) and saves files in app there.

Comment: Did you mean that your application needs to use the correct output path to save the files to the persisted location?

Comment: Yea need to save in correct output path, not in root like i did before.